# Pandas Condensing Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am currently trying to use the groupby function in Pandas to conglomerate some CSV data.

This is a small sample of the data I have currently in a CSV:

```
Company,School,Number,Type
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,3,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,4,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,1,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,4,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,3,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,3,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,DeVry Institute of Technology,4,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,DeVry Institute of Technology,4,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,DeVry Institute of Learning,16,   For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,DeVry Institute of Learning,9,    
Career Education Corporation,Le Cordon Blue College of Culinary Arts,6,For-Profit
Career Education Corporation,Le Cordon Blue College of Culinary Arts,23,For-Profit
```

As it currently stands, there are a number of repetitions of the same "School" column (Carrington, Devry, etc.), and I want to condense them down. More specifically, I want to have 1 row for every unique school that also sums the Number for all instances of that school, but retains the name of the company that owns that school (the first column) and the type of the school (the last column).

The final product would look like this:

```
Company,School,Number,Type
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,Carrington,18,For-Profit,
Adtelem Global Education Inc., DeVry Institute of Technology,8,For-Profit
Adtelem Global Education Inc.,DeVry Institute of Learning,25,For-Profit
Career Education Corporation,Le Cordon Blue College of Culinary Arts,29,For-Profit
```

I have used the following code:

```
data2 = data.groupby("School").sum()
```

However, when I do this I also lose the Company and Type attached to each school. I know the solution is rather basic, but I am new to Pandas, so any help you all can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df.groupby('School', as_index=False)\
    .agg({'Company' : 'first', 'Type' : 'first', 'Number' : 'sum'})

                                    School                        Company  \
0                               Carrington  Adtelem Global Education Inc.   
1              DeVry Institute of Learning  Adtelem Global Education Inc.   
2            DeVry Institute of Technology  Adtelem Global Education Inc.   
3  Le Cordon Blue College of Culinary Arts   Career Education Corporation   

   Number        Type  
0      18  For-Profit  
1      25  For-Profit  
2       8  For-Profit  
3      29  For-Profit
```

I believe it's better to explicitly aggregate all columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a list of columns to group by

```
data2 = data.groupby(["School", "Company", "Type"]).sum()
```